# I am trying to rename multiple files programmatically but when i run code it deletes all files from given folder

Tags: python

I've written the script below to rename all files in a folder. But instead of renaming all filenames inside the folder, it is deleting the files in the folder and no errors are thrown while executing this code.

```py
    import os
    i = 0
    for file in os.listdir():  
        src = file 
        dst = "gain" + str(i) + ".tfw"  
        dst = 'D:\Share' + dst  
        os.rename(src, dst) 
        i += 1
```

Comment: It's not deleting the files, it's moving them. Because that's what the code you wrote does. You'll find your files on the `D:` drive.

Comment: before you use `rename(src, dst)` you should use only `print(src, dst)` to check if you correctly created pathes. When you are sure that pathes are correct then you should use `rename`

Comment: your files have names `"D:\Sharegain"+str(i)+".tfw"` - maybe you need \ after `Share` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pathlib in this case and i think its looks nicer

```py
from pathlib import Path
root_dir = Path('/path/to/folder')
for i, f in enumerate(root_dir.iterdir()):
     f.rename(f.parent / "gain{}.tfw".format(i))
```

Also don't override the file varible name, its bad practice